# Is there any reason not to use OrientDB?

Tags: mongodb, neo4j, nosql

I've been experimenting with many noSQL databases. I just 'stumbled' upon **OrientDB**, which apparently is a hybrid of a document storage such as **MongoDB** and a graph database such as **Neo4j**.

I read in some blog that OrientDB performs at least as good, if not better, than Neo4j, while also offering more complex types like MongoDB would.

is there any reason to opt for either MongoDB or Neo4j? What's the catch? What am I missing? How does it compare to using MongoDB for document storage in conjunction with Neo4j for graph storage (for instance, user data in MongoDB, relationships in Neo4j)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Main reason**: Bugs, lots of them.

**Secondary reason**: Lack of proper documentation.
Last time we tried to use Orient it was impossible to use at scale in a production environment.
Why? Simply because we couldn't move beyond development mode. We could not even move it to testing.
What are those bugs?
You can read the forums about all those or just google "bugs" "orientdb".
Having said that, the technology looks promising and we might give it another go in two years when it is more mature.

***Why does it have so many bugs?***

Like someone said, a hybrid db is a complex thing to tackle, lots of room for errors. It's hard.

Another aspect was that Orient tried to build too many features instead of stabilizing and cleaning existing ones. Why they did this? I guess it's a matter of company valuations and time to market.

Comment: I have used OrientDB commercially since V2.1. Now on V3.0.9. They improved massively in performance and fixed many bugs. The team is proactive tackling problems as soon as reported. Documentation: things are somewhat difficult to find and there are things that are not documented well or not documented at all that you will have to be googling around or experimenting until you crack them. The biggest pros are "SQL language" (anyone with SQL experience can pick it up quickly) and the "class inheritance concept" (structure your "tables" right and you will rock).

Comment: For anyone coming across this post, I highly suggest you take a look at the [OrientDB github repo](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb) and judge for yourself the insane amount of work the OrientDB team has put in to make the software more stable. As of now, **OrientDB v3.024** is out and the software is definitely mature at this point. I highly recommend you give OrientDB a try as its speed and flexibility is unparalleled by any other graph db.

Comment: @Jean-Paul repo is a good place to look, but how are you judging that? There 17% of issues are still open, with the oldest issue dating as far back as 2015 with not so much as a single comment. One complaint from past users is that OrientDB prioritises features over bug fixes, and that it was not production-ready (this was around version 2.1, 2.2. At this point there were several troublesome bugs, like adding an `ORDER BY` clause to a statement with no `LIMIT` would yield 0 results). One particularly mad individual even wrote a [blog about their experience](http://orientdbleaks.blogspot.com/).

Comment: @Jean-Paul do you currently use OrientDB in production? It could be that it was just a case of promoting a bit too much before it was fully ready.

Answer (score 30):

(Disclaimer: I'm the founder of the OrientDB project)

Even if about 50% of the OrientDB users are using OrientDB as a Graph Database (a replacement for Neo4j), the idea behind OrientDB was to build the first Open Source Multi-Model database. 6 years ago the word "Multi-Model" didn't exist, but now DBMS vendors like DataStax (Cassandra), MongoDB and CouchBase are becoming Multi-Model or they announced to be Multi-Model in the upcoming future. This is, of course, a validation of the Multi-Model concept OrientDB created a long time ago.

That said, at the beginning, the OrientDB's goal wasn't to have "just" a super stable Graph Database, but rather experiment with the Multi-Model concept. So it's partially true that the team was more focused on adding new models (you can see them as features) than making OrientDB rock-solid and **super easy to use for the beginner**.

However, thousands of companies are already in production with OrientDB. Look at [Success Stories](http://orientdb.com/success/) and [Press](http://orientdb.com/press/), just to name a few of them.

Starting from release 2.2, the OrientDB team priority is changed: now that the Multi-Model concept is stable, it was time to make OrientDB super rock-solid. If you have tried OrientDB before 2.2, I suggest giving OrientDB v.2.2.x a chance.  In order to help new users, the [documentation](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/) has been improved for beginner usage too.

Is OrientDB perfect? No DBMS is bug-free, but OrientDB has one of the lowest bugs in comparison to other DBMSs. Look at [Let's Talk about OrientDB Stability, Code Coverage and Bugs](http://orientdb.com/orientdb-stability-bugs-benchmark/) (that post is not updated: it reports 343 bugs but, checking today, the number of open bugs for OrientDB project is 254. I didn't check if the other DBMSs that are part of the benchmark improved their numbers too.)

If you already have experience with Neo4j, OrientDB should be quite easy to use. If you used the TinkerPop/Gremlin standard, OrientDB is a drop-in replacement, otherwise, it requires some work, especially to translate Cypher to OrientDB SQL (use the OrientDB [MATCH](http://orientdb.com/pattern-matching-with-orientdb/) operator!). Many users already switched to OrientDB from Neo4j and they report comparable or even better performance.

My suggestion is: try OrientDB v2.2.x. If it's too complicated or doesn't work well for your use case, please don't drop it immediately, but try to ask help on StackOverflow or the [Community Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/orient-database) first.

Comment: We are exploring orientdb for our use case and so far seems without bugs during the development phase.